# Android OpenGL: How to change bitmap attached to texture?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have created a texture like this

```
public int createTexture(Bitmap bitmap){
 final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];
 GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
 glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);       
 glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
 // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
 GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0); 
 return textureHandle[0];
}
```

Now based on the user input I want to update my `Texture` with the new `Bitmap`. I tried recalling same function with different `Bitmap` but its not getting updated. Am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT**

I tried as Tommy said in his answer but no use. Let me elaborate how I am using textures.

```
public void changeFilter(){
  //create required bitmap here
  if(mTextureDataHandle1==0) 
    mTextureDataHandle1 =loadTexture(bitmap); 
  else 
      updateTexture(mTextureDataHandle1);
}
```

In `onDrawFrame`

```
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle1);
 glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle1, 1);
```

Comment: When you update the texture, what thread are you making those calls from? You have to make all OpenGL calls from the rendering thread.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I am doing it from rendering thread

Comment: @RetoKoradi You are right. It was getting called out of GL thread. Do you have an idea why simply calling `updateTexture`  going off the GL thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That method both creates a new texture and uploads a `Bitmap` to it. It sounds like you want to do the second thing but not the first? If so then provide the `int` texture name as a parameter rather than receiving it as a result, and skip straight to the `glBindTexure` (i.e. omit the `glGenTextures`, which is what creates the new texture).

E.g.

```
public int createTexture(Bitmap bitmap){
 final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];
 GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
 glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);       
 glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
 updateTexture(textureHandle[0], bitmap);
 return textureHandle[0];
}

public void updateTexture(int textureName, Bitmap bitmap) {
 glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);       
 // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
 GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0); 
}
```

So the bit where you upload a `Bitmap` is factored out from the bit where you create a texture and set its filtering type; to update an existing texture use the `int` you got earlier and call directly into `updateTexture`.

Comment: I tried as you said. I  skipped `glGenTextures` if the id of the texture is not equal to 0 but no use. I hope this is what you said. Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: Hang on; I'll be at a computer in about fifteen minutes — I'll try to add some sample code then. Getting it done from a phone proved too difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the code.. I tried the same thing but  its coming back with the same texture.. `if(mTextureDataHandle1==0)
               mTextureDataHandle1 =loadTexture(bitmap);
            else updateTexture(mTextureDataHandle1);` this is how I am calling those methods

Comment: Okay. Is the second `Bitmap` definitely acceptable as a texture? What happens if you check `glGetError`? The lack of universal support for non-power-of-two textures once bit me when porting something from iOS (where there's only one GPU family so sometimes you forget that you're not writing to spec).

Comment: I don't think that is the problem because both time I am using same size `Bitmap` and I updated my question for more clarity. Please check once you get free time..

Comment: I got the problem just now. `updateTexture` was getting called from different thread. I solved by using `GLSurfaceView.queueEvent` method. But I have no idea why simply calling `updateTexture` going off the GL thread. Please let me know if you have any idea. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply be not on the OpenGL rendering thread when changing the Bitmap. When you change the Bitmap, save in a boolean that you did so, and then only in the rendering thread call texImage2D.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the techniques in the above responses I got horrible performance. If **what you want is to update the texture *live* as in 60 fps** there is a better way. BTW I didn't find documentation on it, I had to pull and pieces together from different sources.

(1) you have to tell OpenGL extensions to use external textures. That is when defining your texture instead of using GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 you use **GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES**

(2) you have to use the classes Surface and SurfaceTexture. (look into consumers and producers for more into. They work like a server/client but instead the architecture is called consumer/producer)

(3) You have to enable an extension on your fragment shader. You can't use sampler2D you have to use **samplerExternalOES**. To enable the extension you put the following line at the top of your shader code:

> **#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external: require**

[Code snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX2VT.png)

The above is a snapshot of my code, below is the fragment shader

[Fragment shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQRxw.png)